# Encrypt / Decrypt with Private key

Tags: php, flash, security, encryption, private-key

I would like to implement some security in some of the Flash/PHP applications that I have.

I have some Flash apps that communicate with PHP files, and the PHP is sending the data as get string ( e.g.: `name=John&sname=Doe&age=24&balance=12.4` ). Instead of all these variables, I would like it to send a single variable ( e.g.: `flashvar=jr9afgaw9-fg90agfawf7gw` ) that would contain those values, so then Flash would decrypt the string and get the *real and useful* vars.

I want to encrypt this using a private key and use the same private key to decrypt this inside Flash. If someone would want to decode the message PHP sends, he would have to decompile the flash file and find the private key I'm using in Flash to decode the message and then decode it.

The reason I posted here is because I want to use an encryption algorithm that allows only the use of a private key for encryption/decryption.

I'm new in the cryptography field and I'd like some suggestions for this.

Thank you!

Comment: Why google? Just BING it

Comment: @Gens because he wants valid results :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "shared private key" is refered to as a symmetric key. The standard symmetric algorithm in use today is [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). I have no idea if php, or flash, have the capability of using AES (Google does), but if they do, you could hard code an AES key in your code and use it to encrypt and decrypt data. However, hard coding a key is very bad cryptography and is little more than obfuscation.

Another thing to keep in mind is the cipher mode you are using. Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) requires the use of an initialization vector (sort of like a salt for a hash), so two of the same values encrypted with the same key, but different IV, will result in differen cipher text. ECB does not need an initialization vector, but is less secure. For your needs I would go with ECB so you dont have to worry about an IV.

Google is a very good way of finding information, you should use it.

Comment: thank you for the information. the idea was to actually code the algorithms as function in both languages(PHP and FLASH) and then include them and use them , but I found out that PHP and FLASH have preintegrated RIJNDAEL 256 functions and I will probably go with that.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search, I saw that ActionScript 3 has support for encryption throught [ASCrypt3](http://ascrypt3.riaforge.org/) library. According to the website, AES Rijndael is supported.

Rijndael is also supported in PHP using the [mcrypt](http://php.net/mcrypt) extension. Here's a pretty good example [taken from the manual](http://php.net/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php):

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$key = "This is a very secret key";
$text = "Meet me at 11 o'clock behind the monument.";
echo strlen($text) . "\n";

$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
echo strlen($crypttext) . "\n";
```

Comment: can anyone confirm that the ASCRYPT3 library is fully functional ? I used this PHP function , but I cant decrypt the output in flash : function encrypt($text){
 $key = "53cded30ff7ba54d65b939fd594e3d63";
 $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC); //get vector size on CBC mode 
 $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND); //Creating the vector
 $cryptedtext = mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); //Encrypting using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 algorithm 
 return base64_encode($cryptedtext);
}

Answer (score 0):

If You want to encrypt data I would go with the [ASCrypt3o](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) library.
It works very well and supports multiple types of encryption.
You can see a demo of it [here](http://crypto.hurlant.com/demo/) click on the secret key tab.